# Apple developer membership expires alert not removing

Tags: iphone-developer-program

Before one month in Apple member centre page I got one alert like 
"Your Developer Program Membership expires in 3 days.
Renew your membership to keep your access to Apple Developer Program benefits and services."

So I went through `Renew Membership` link and successfully completed payment before one week.

After that I got mail from apple says process will take two days to complete.

But still now I can see text in member centre same as above 
(Your Developer Program Membership expires in 3 days.
Renew your membership to keep your access to Apple Developer Program benefits and services.)

Is that like for everyone (or) I have to do something more (or) It will automatically disappear after the expiration date?

Answer (score 1):

Apple says, "If your membership is still active when you renew, your new membership will activate as soon as your current membership expires and you will receive two (2) new TSIs."

https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/